# Google API Explorer deprecated for Endpoints APIs?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-apis-explorer, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have a REST API published to Google Endpoints and have been using the API Explorer to interact with it. When I accessed API Explorer this week I found this notice:

"This site is deprecated for Endpoints APIs. For exploring and testing Endpoints APIs, try the Cloud Endpoints Portal."

I can't find any other information such as when this service will be terminated. Anybody have a link or other information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APIs Explorer not going away so much as moving to [Cloud Endpoints Portals](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/dev-portal-overview). You still get an APIs Explorer there with all the same features, and more. It's just a newer format more specific to your API, with more detail and better navigation.

As mentioned on that page, you can try out the [demo](https://endpointsportal.endpoints-portal-demo.cloud.goog/), including trying out your own API spec using the "Try your own API!" button.

Comment: It's a lot to take in. BTW, doesn't it seem redundant to create an OpenAPI document from the source code and then deploy both the document and the source code? What's up with that?

Comment: Most users of Endpoints are not using the Frameworks, so they write the OpenAPI document by hand or use a different generator.

Comment: I finally got around to enabling Endpoints for my API and deploying the OpenAPI doc. I was thrilled to see my API in the Endpoints portal with all the method parameters! But all methods fail with a 401: "Invalid token". Even those such as `list` with no required parameters. Authentication requirements are listed as None. The API still works using the Python API client. I'm stumped.

Comment: @TomRussell That sounds like a separate issue which should probably be asked as a separate question/post.